# Windows Task-Scheduler: can one start an application whenever another one gets started?

Tags: windows, outlook

I am seeking a possibility to always trigger a second application whenever another application gets started (ideally: right before the latter gets started but probably more or less "at the same time" will suffice).

The issue at hand is, that our company's IT folks for some to me unexplicable reason insist on constantly "adjusting" some Windows registry entries. One of those entries is the flag to memorize the passwords for the mail servers that Outlook keeps polling. Having to re-enter these passwords over and over again is driving me nuts and so meanwhile I also figured out which entries I have to revert to stop this nonsense. I thus now have a .reg file that I always "apply" to the registry right before starting Outlook and that helps me to maintain mental health.

But it is of course tedious to always have to click TWO icons in sequence, when opening my mail app. (Outlook). So, while I could certainly replace all Outlook "shortcuts" with shortcuts to a script file first applying the registry patch and only then starting Outlook I was wondering whether there wouldn't be a more elegant solution.

My question thus: is there an option or tool (e.g. in Windows' task-scheduler) to trigger the start of an application 'B' whenever a specific application 'A' gets is (or is about to be) started?

Comment: did you think on creating a batch file that will launch both applications when clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in paragraph 3. But I was looking for something more AOP-like...  ;-)